# How to open a link directly from Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I use Colorzilla a lot while building simple prototypes, is there anyway that I can open a certain website link by typing a command in Atom directly? Something like:

```
link:open-colorzilla
```

and than say in some snippet file I have `colorzilla` set to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Is this possible, because this would be brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

It might not work exactly the way you described above, but the [browser-plus](https://atom.io/packages/browser-plus) package might work for your case.

It will open a browser in your Atom instance, allowing you to browse the web directly from within Atom. There are a couple of default keyboard shortcuts opening frequently used web sites like Stack Overflow, Google or DevDocs, and it allows you to define your own favorite custom URL (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) - you can configure it to open Colorzilla.

Again, it's not 100% percent what you're looking for, but it comes pretty close.

Comment: awesome, will try it !

Answer (score 1):

But I found this question when asking search engine how directly open URLs from an edited text in Atom into the external browser.

If you searched this too, I want to tell you about small [open-path](https://atom.io/packages/open-path) plugin. It open file or URL under cursor by a two-key combination on Mac cmd-o and ctrl-o on Windows/Linux (by default). Also, it copy image size if you need:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a [flex-tool-bar plugin](https://atom.io/packages/flex-tool-bar) (it need to install [tool-bar package](https://atom.io/packages/tool-bar)), which makes custom buttons.You can choose different icons from free biggest libraries.

For example, I am using buttons: open priority URLs in the external browser, git diff, js beautify, markdown, restart atom buttons and other. 
My settings:

```
[
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "document"
    callback: "application:new-file"
    tooltip: "New File"
    iconset: "ion"
  }
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "folder"
    callback: "application:open-file"
    tooltip: "Open..."
    iconset: "ion"
  }
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "save"
    callback: "core:save"
    tooltip: "Save"
    iconset: "fa"
  }
  {
    type: "spacer"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "columns"
    iconset: "fa"
    callback: ["pane:split-right", "pane:split-right"]
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "fire"
    callback: "atom-beautify:beautify-editor"
    tooltip: "JS beautify"
    iconset: "fa"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "shuffle"
    callback: "git-diff:toggle-diff-list"
    iconset: "ion"
  }

  {
    type: "spacer"
  }

    {
      type: "button"
      icon: "markdown"
      callback: "markdown-preview:toggle"
      disable: "!markdown"
    }

  {
    type: "url"
    icon: "bitbucket"
    url: "https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/repositories"
    tooltip: "My bitbucket repos"
    iconset: "fa"
  }

  {
    type: "url"
    icon: "fighter-jet"
    url: "https://***.atlassian.net/secure/***"
    tooltip: "Jira My Board"
    iconset: "fa"
  }

  {
    type: "url"
    icon: "wink"
    url: "https://****.world"
    tooltip: "My Production"
    iconset: "icomoon"
  }

  {
    type: "url"
    icon: "glass2"
    url: "https://***.world/explore/"
    tooltip: "Explorer Prod"
    iconset: "icomoon"
  }

  {
    type: "spacer"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "refresh"
    callback: "window:reload"
    tooltip: "Reload window"
    iconset: "ion"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "gear-a"
    callback: "settings-view:open"
    tooltip: "Open Settings View"
    iconset: "ion"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "plug"
    callback: "user:restart"
    tooltip: "Restart Atom"
  }

  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "terminal"
    callback: "command-palette:toggle"
    tooltip: "Command Palette"
  }

]
```